# jboss-cli: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am having trouble getting to jboss-cli in Wildfly 9.0.1.Final working. When running jboss-cli or jboss-cli.bat inside of the JBOSS_HOME/bin folder, it fails returning "The system cannot find the path specified."

I have tried the following to fix this:

- Modifying standalone.conf.bat and standalone.conf, changing the JAVA_HOME to to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162. The installation exists, and contains /bin/java
- Using "" and "\" instead of "/"
- Setting the JBOSS_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and PATH environment variables, with JBOSS_HOME being my root Wildfly folder, JAVA_HOME being C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162, and PATH having an entry that is C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin.

What other options do I have to get jboss-cli working?

Comment: I don't use WIndows with JBoss but I recommend you get the original files back and simply set JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME env. vars. with normal backslashes. If you're doing this in a terminal, be sure to quote paths with spaces in them, e.g. ```set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162"```

Comment: Tried your suggestions and stumbled across the answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being with JAVA_HOME, it was a multiple entry environment variable, and Windows represents that with a ';' at the end, so jboss-cli was failing to parse it. Even though the entry in the list was "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162", the actual text stores was "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162;"

Comment: *it was a multiple entry environment variable* You can't have such a thing. Only one JAVA_HOME allowed so the path separator should never be there

Comment: Yes you can, here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y25QT.png. Whether the path separator should or should not be there isn't in question, it obviously shouldn't. But it CAN be there, and the environment variable editing window does not show the path separator if it exists in the environment variable string.

Comment: *Yes you can, here's an example* Well, good luck when you execute ```%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java``` with that, which is the essential point of the variable ;) Obviously you can put any arbitrary string in there in that env var window

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't work with the separator there, but I didn't notice it when I made the post. If I had, there wouldn't be a post, the setup in a Stack Overflow question not working is practically tautological.

Comment: It's a good thing I came across this post.  In my case, my JAVA_HOME variable was set  incorrectly to "C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8.0_271".  To all appearances, jboss-cli.bat ran all the way through before giving the error message.  I had thought some intermediate batch file was in the wrong place.  After seeing this, I spotted the incorrect JAVA_HOME setting.